# Spectrum Colour Picker into theme

Tags: jquery, css

There is something similar but mine is a more basic question. I would like to use " Spectrum Colour Picker " ( https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/ ) in php script theme I have. I need to bind the colour changes to a few css classes to achieve this. I got as much as adding colour picker into the template but still at bay on binding it to css classes to change colours ( and save it ). A helping hand would be great.

-- Edit ----

This is what I have now

```js
$("#flat").spectrum({
    flat: true,
    showInput: true
});
```

```html
<script src='spectrum.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='spectrum.css' />

<input type='text' id="flat" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post some code?